# mobile different web view magento2.1

Tags: magento2

How can i use user agent in mobile for different view?
I mean want to see different webpage on mobile from desktop
any suggestion?
Know it on PHP on Magento2 i don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new theme with the parent as your current theme.
Next set up the new theme as an exception for the mobile.
In the new theme, you can override your files

Comment: Is it works  on any mobile devices?

Comment: Yes, this is agent detection

Answer (score 1):

you can installed below extension and configure this extension working for you 
[https://marketplace.magento.com/eadesignro-module-mobiledetect.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Nxw.png)

or 
User agent rule

```
iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini
```

Try to create multiple exceptions for each device [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a new theme to your current store in `admin` -> `content` -> `Design` -> `Configuration` as shown in image.

[image]

Select the theme you want to show from `Theme Name` dropdown.